# Em "vou pagar com pix", estou usando uma palavra (pix) já incorporada à língua portuguesa?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, siglas

**Pix**, uma forma de transferência bancária criada pelo Banco Central do Brasil em outubro de 2020,  tornou-se uma palavra (ou será sigla) cada vez mais usada em pt-BR. Mas, o que significa pix?  É uma sigla ou uma palavra?  Deve ser escrita com letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas?  E, mais importante, já é considerada uma palavra da língua portuguesa?  Existe algo semelhante em pt-PT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Pix é um meio de pagamento desenvolvido pelo Banco Central do Brasil e já conta com uma página própria no [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pix) (até mesmo em inglês - [*Pix (electronic payment system)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pix_(electronic_payment_system))).

Na [página oficial do Pix](https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/pix) no site do Banco Central, há um botão com o texto "*Construção da marca Pix*", que exibe um gif mostrando o processo de criação da marca (logo e nome) Pix. O conceito visual foi criado baseado em tecnologia, transação e pixel:

> #### Definição de marca única
>
> A existência de uma marca única é imprescindível para que os usuários (pagadores e recebedores) identifiquem esse novo meio de realizar pagamentos e transferências de uma forma clara e inequívoca. A identidade visual facilitará o entendimento e a adoção do instrumento. As marcas individuais que representam cada um dos prestadores de serviços de pagamento (instituições financeiras e de pagamento) poderão ser dispostas juntamente com a marca Pix, na forma e nas condições divulgadas no regulamento do Pix e documentos anexos.
>
> #### Processo de criação
>
> [image: Gif mostrando o processo de criação do logo e do nome como "Conceito visual baseado em tecnologia, transação, pixel".]

Então, Pix é uma marca e, portanto, deve ser escrito com a primeira letra maiúscula e não é considerado uma palavra da língua portuguesa (ou qualquer outra língua).

Aparentemente, o nome é derivado diretamente da palavra "pixel", mas não encontrei nenhuma confirmação explícita quanto a isso (apenas implícitas, como no GIF acima).